# Displaying images from firefox add-on's data directory in webpage

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am writing a firefox addon and have a content script that does my DOM manipulation as I want, but I now want to display some images from my add-on's data directory in the manipulated webpage (rather than link to them on a remote server) but I'm not sure how to do it.

I see that communication between the add-on module and content script should be done via port.emit, but the [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/using_port#port.emit()) says that the parameter has to be JSON serializable.

Has anyone done this before? I feel that I've missed something.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys, not forgotten about this, just haven't had a chance to check out your suggestions, then I'll mark an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you can hard code the `resource:` uri to the data directory, it is better to construct it at runtime. This is done with the help of the `@loader/options` pseudo module, but a forward compatible way would be through the `self` module. If you don't have other reason to use the `port` mechanism, then you can pass the uri to the content script through the `contentScriptOptions` parameter. Your content script can access it from `self.options`. The following code will insert the `mylogo.jpg` at every page of the `mozilla.org` domain.

```js
// var options = require("@loader/options");
// options.prefixURI + options.name + "/data/" works now but may change in the future
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
var self = require("sdk/self");

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*.mozilla.org",
  contentScriptOptions: {prefixDataURI: self.data.url("")},
  contentScriptWhen: "ready",
  contentScript: "var img = document.createElement('img');" +
                 "img.src = self.options.prefixDataURI + 'mylogo.jpg';" +
                 "document.body.appendChild(img);"
});
```

Comment: This is true - the resource path format has changed in the past and could change in the future, so you should always derive it using self.data.url().

Comment: @canuckistani you 're right, I changed the code to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

I've done this in a bootstrap addon with the `contentaccessible` param in the chrome.manifest here: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9406437

For addon-sdk, which it sounds like you are doing, I think do this: just drop your images into your data folder. Then with the `self.data.url('img_name')` it gives you a `resource://` path, use that path in the webpages. It should work, resource paths don't have the security issue Im pretty sure.